# adding a character in a column in bash

Tags: bash

I need to add the character " in a column inside a file.

```
London,20170616,16,Fri,0,21.5,11.0,3466,16.120,3.71,0,37,11
London,20170617,17,Sat,0,20.8,10.8,3998,342.55,6.89,0,0,0
London,20170618,18,Sun,0,20.1,7.5,3853,335.29,4.62,0,0,0
London,20170619,19,Mon,0,19.4,4.1,3525,255.07,0.49,0,3,0
London,20170620,20,Tue,0.1,22.4,8.7,3632,327.02,1.91,0,0,0
London,20170621,21,Wed,0.3,21.5,11.3,3594,322.33,4.20,0,3,3.2
```

In the 4th, 9th and 10 th column, I have to add ", for example... "Fri"

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: do you want to modify same file or you want to create a different file?

Comment: This is a requirements dump and shows absolutely no effort on your part. That's not how SO works.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think it's perfectly reasonable. They've got sample data, desired results, and an understandable explanation for transformation. It can be answered with a short answer and there is nothing vague happening. The only thing I don't like is that it shows little research effort since this can be done probably 10 different ways on the command line.

Comment: @JNevile. I like your answer but I don't think it's fair to anyone else to enable this sort of behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $1,$2,$3,"\""$4"\"",$5,$6,$7,$8,"\""$9"\"","\""$10"\"",$11,$12,$13}' yourfile > outfile
```

Here `awk` is:

1. Setting the Field Separator `FS` and the Output Field Seperator `OFS` to a comma before processing the file (`BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}`)
2. Printing out each column/field and sticking a double quote around the specified columns (`print $1,$2,$3,"\""$4"\"",$5,$6,$7,$8,"\""$9"\"","\""$10"\"",$11,$12,$13`)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$4="\""$4"\"";$9="\""$9"\"";$10="\""$10"\"";}1' file
```

field separator and output field separator is comma. 
in `awk`, since 1 always is true, it performs default operation `{print $0}`, hence prints the current line stored in `$0`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v q=\" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$4=q$4q;$9=q$9q;$10=q$10q}1' file

London,20170616,16,"Fri",0,21.5,11.0,3466,"16.120","3.71",0,37,11
London,20170617,17,"Sat",0,20.8,10.8,3998,"342.55","6.89",0,0,0
London,20170618,18,"Sun",0,20.1,7.5,3853,"335.29","4.62",0,0,0
London,20170619,19,"Mon",0,19.4,4.1,3525,"255.07","0.49",0,3,0
London,20170620,20,"Tue",0.1,22.4,8.7,3632,"327.02","1.91",0,0,0
London,20170621,21,"Wed",0.3,21.5,11.3,3594,"322.33","4.20",0,3,3.2
```